# python duplicate_move and snap_selected_to_cursor fails; context is incorrect

Tags: python

I'm new to blender and python.  I thought I'd duplicate a cube I have at (-1, 0, 0 ) and snap it to my 3d cursor, which is at world origin.  Using the scripting view, I created commands found from the console

```
object = bpy.data.objects["MyCube"]
object.select_set(True)
selectedObject = bpy.context.selected_objects
print( "selectedObject = " + str(selectedObject))

bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY', center='MEDIAN')

bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 0), "orient_type":'GLOBAL', "orient_matrix":((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "mirror":True, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False, "use_automerge_and_split":False})

context = bpy.context.area.type
print("Area Type = " + str(context))

bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor(use_offset=False)
```

which outputs:

```
selectedObject = [bpy.data.objects['MyCube']]
Area Type = TEXT_EDITOR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\BlenderWork\Projects\TestOrWork\Cube20.blend\Text", line 38, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

I'm assuming that this is happening because my area type is TEXT_EDITOR, which is where my script is running, NOT the 3dview.

Apparently more is needed then simply 'doing stuff' in the 3dview and copy/pasting commands into a script.

How do I fix this?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - I needed to add

bpy.context.area.type = 'VIEW_3D'

to switch from the text editor to the 3dview, before snap_selected_to_cursor.